# insert data in sqlite database in phonegap when first time load application

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

i have an application write with phonegap , i want when first time my application load , tables and data create and insert in database , but when run my application every time , insert data done again , and load time increase , how can chek if table created dont insert data again ?

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    var dbShell ;

     function onDeviceReady() {

     dbShell = window.openDatabase("BaharNarenj", "1.0", "BaharNarenj", 2000000);

    dbShell.transaction(setupTable,dbErrorHandler,getEntries);

    }

function setupTable(tx){

    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amaken(id INTEGER,title,des,px,py)");     

tx.executeSql('insert into amaken(id,title,des,px,py) values(2,"test","dec","36.566185","55.059502")');     

 tx.executeSql('insert into amaken(id,title,des,px,py) values(4,"test5","dec5","36.566185","55.059502")');  
}



function dbErrorHandler(err){
 alert("DB Error: "+err.message + "\nCode="+err.code);
}


function getEntries() {
alert("done");
}
```

Comment: Isn't there SharedPreference in phonegap?

Answer (score 3):

You can set one flag (like XApp1.0 in following code) in local storage and check that flag's value while subsequent run of the app. Hope this will help you.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var firstrun = window.localStorage.getItem("XApp1.0"); 
    if ( firstrun == null ) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("XApp1.0", "1"); 
        var db = window.openDatabase("XApp", "1.0", "XApp", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
    else {
        // Db Alredy Exists
        var db = window.openDatabase("XApp", "1.0", "XApp", 200000);
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }
}
```